# Spring Boot is ignoring Group Authorities authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using a "spring boot" application and I want to configure the security to use [Group Authority authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#group-authorities).
It seems simple but when I try to log in, Spring always checks the User Authorities instead of Group Authority.

My configuration class is:

```
@Configuration()
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**", "/font-awesome/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
             .usersByUsernameQuery(
                 "select cpf as username, senha as password, ativo as enabled from funcionario where cpf=?")                 
             .groupAuthoritiesByUsername(
                 "select g.id, g.nome, p.nome " +
                 "from grupo g, funcionario_grupo fg, grupo_permissoes gp, permissoes p " +
                 "where gf.username = ? and g.id = gp.grupo_id and g.id = fg.group_id gp.permissoes_id = p.id");
    }
}
```

I tried with several ways to configure Spring to use my groupAuthoritiesByUsername, even with XML, but have had no success.

Someone could help me, what I'm doing wrong? What is missing?

Comment: Fixed grammar and cleaned up source code.

Comment: Sorry about my grammar, I'm brazilian, I'm not fluent in english =/
My code is small, IMHO I think is readable.

Comment: Oops!  My comment was supposed to be about the edit I made, not go here.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my configuration, but at the end I could solve the problem creating a custom UserDetailService, I did somethink like http://www.sivalabs.in/2014/03/springmvc4-spring-data-jpa.html just changing a little bit to attend my need

Answer (score 0):

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ...
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().getUserDetailsService().setEnableAuthorities(false);
    ...
}
```